# Docker - Nodejs to Mongodb connection works but collection is null

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker

I am trying to connect from NodeJS Docker container to MongoDB Docker container. I can access the MongoDb from a client such as RoboMongo.

But in NodeJS it connects to the database but the db is null and I get an error when trying to get a collection.

```
 url = 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/mydb';

router.get('/api/v1/test', function (req, res, next) {

      MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {

          var collection = db.collection('myApptbl');   

       });
});
```

I am getting the below error in my docker logs.

```
/usr/src/myapp/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js:225
          throw err
          ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'collection' of null

 at /usr/src/myapp/server.js:52:26
    at connectCallback (/usr/src/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js:315:5)
    at /usr/src/myapp/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js:222:11
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:67:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
```

Can you please help or provide suggestions on why I am getting this error.

Comment: Are mongodb and nodejs running inside the same container?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your connection string `mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/mydb` is telling your NodeJS app connect to MongoDB in the same container by referencing `127.0.0.1` (localhost).

You want to tell it to connect to the MongoDB container, depending on how you've started your MongoDB container, with something like `mongodb://mongodb:27017/mydb`.

If you've started your containers with something like `docker-compose`, you should be able to use the name of the service:

```
...

services:

    mongodb: <--- you can use this in your connection string
        image: xxx

    your-node-app:
        image: xxx
```

If you're not using `docker-compose` and are using `--link`, you will need to reference the name of the link in your connection string.

E.g.,

```
docker run -d --name mongodb mongodb

docker run -d --link mongodb:mongodb your-node-app
```

**Note**: The reason for this is because docker will add an entry to your `/etc/hosts` file that point the service name / link name to the private IP address of the linked container.